# Accessibility Node Info Get Image Content

Tags: android, image, view, accessibilityservice

I am making an app for automating few tasks. I am able to do the required interaction with the app but i want to show information from that app on an overlay. What i want to know is how to get image from AccessibilityNodeInfo instance pointing to an ImageView ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do out of curiosity? Google has reserved accessibility service for apps that only help users with a disability etc.

You would typically do this the same way you use accessibility service for everything else. Search specifically for the id of the imageView in the node.

Comment: I am trying to automate a small task. I use steam app which require checking on each item checkbox to confirm it. For me sometime i have to sell 100-1000 items and clicking on each item is very tedious and time consuming. This app does not provide check all affordance to probably constraint user from mistakenly checking all and selling. But for someone like me who gotta do it for hundreds of items this task become serious burden.

Comment: I am able to check all items using Accessibility service but i also want to group the items and display it in the overlay so i can only select a group of items. The extracting image part is to just provide visual aid to user for immediate perception of item.